# Twitter4J Api with java get json object of all followers

Tags: java, twitter4j

creating java application where  i  am using twitter4j  api  and i need to get all followers  and  followings in  json  object. but  i  am not able to get it. giving me error as

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

please give some link for tutorials or  help  me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Without code example hard to think.

Comment: Why don't you search for "Bad Authentication Data Twitter4J Twitter" in a search engine??

Comment: lets do this step by step, please post the code about OAuth...

Comment: just  i  puted  link  to  Browser..  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json